# Uniform continuity of the CDF of a continuous Random variable.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, uniform-continuity

A random variable X is continuous if and only if  it's CDF F is continuous.But how can we prove F to be uniform continuous?

Answer (score 0):

If $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and has (finite) limits at $\pm\infty$ then $F$ is uniformly continuous.

You should concoct your own proof of this, starting with "let $\epsilon>0$". A sort of high-level proof, purposely chosen so as not to give you that proof you should be looking for: $F$ extends to a continuous function $F:[-\infty,\infty]\to\Bbb R$, and $[-\infty,\infty]$ is a compact metric space...

Comment: Can I use the fact that since F is a bdd monotone function(CDF),hence the limits are finite?

Comment: I can't say - what you're allowed to use depends on whoever assigned the problem. But if it were up to me I'd say yes, you can use that.